# Get IFTA (State Miles)

Tags: azure-maps

I used postman to get a route and it returned the instructions, the polygon, traffic information, but I didn't see where you can request state miles breakdown.

Can the azure maps return miles per state breakdown?
I need this to calculate IFTA per trip.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Maps currently does not have an option to return the distances travelled within states that a route crosses. This is however something that is being investigated as a future feature.